# WP_Query: I don't want to reset the posts & order column

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type "members"

Im using bootstrap 3 to make a carousel displaying them so each item of the carousel has 4 "members" like:

```
<div class="item active">
 <div class="row">
  <?
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'equipo', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $some_meta 'meta', true );
  ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <h4><? the_title(); ?></h4>
        <p class="meta"><? echo $some_meta; ?></p>
      </div><!-- thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- col md 3 -->
    <? endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- row -->
 </div><!-- item active -->
```

So in the second carousel item (that has another 4 members) I want to make a new query to display the next 4 members in the database:

```
<div class="item"> <!-- NOTE THERE'S NO "ACTIVE" SO ITS THE SECOND ITEM --> 
 <div class="row">
  <?
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'equipo', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $some_meta 'meta', true );
  ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <h4><? the_title(); ?></h4>
        <p class="meta"><? echo $some_meta; ?></p>
      </div><!-- thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- col md 3 -->
    <? endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- row -->
 </div><!-- item active -->
```

But it displays the same first 4 members.
How can I tell wordpress not to reset the query or something like that?
And my second question: Does anyone know how to order the way that custom posts displays? Maybe with tags or a more elegant solution, making an "order column" in the backend so I cant put a number for ordering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one is surely helps you.

[1] http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Install this plugin and simply insert new div at last your displaying post code.

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></ul>    
</div>
```

Your code will probably look like this:

```
<div class="item"> <!-- NOTE THERE'S NO "ACTIVE" SO ITS THE SECOND ITEM --> 
 <div class="row">
  <?
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'equipo', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $some_meta 'meta', true );
  ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <h4><? the_title(); ?></h4>
        <p class="meta"><? echo $some_meta; ?></p>
      </div><!-- thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- col md 3 -->
    <? endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- row -->
 </div><!-- item active -->
 <div class="pagination">
    <ul><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></ul>    
 </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't solve it.
I don't want to make pagination, I just want the second query to start from the 1st ended.
Thanks anyway man